# Apache Camel: I can't get an object out of the body and transform it

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, apache-camel

Here is if do so: body -> string -> user

```java
    .to("direct:httpClient")
    .process(new Processor() {
        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws JsonProcessingException {
            String body = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
            User[] users = jacksonDataFormat.getObjectMapper().readValue(body, User[].class);
        }
    })
```

This option works great, but if you do this:

```java
User [] body = exchange.getIn().getBody(User[].class);
```

body -> user, it doesn't work. User always null.

For clarity:

```
from("timer://test?period=2000")
                .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD).constant(HttpMethod.GET)
                .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/json"))
                .convertBodyTo(User[].class)
                .to("http://localhost:8085/api/user")
                .process(exchange -> System.out.println(exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class)))
```

Console output:

```
[
   {
      "name":"BLA"
   },
   {
      "name":"BLA"
   },
   {
      "name":"BLA"
   }
]
```

If so:

```
from("timer://test?period=2000")
                .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD).constant(HttpMethod.GET)
                .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/json"))
                .convertBodyTo(User[].class)
                .to("http://localhost:8085/api/user")
                .process(exchange -> System.out.println(exchange.getIn().getBody(User[].class)))
```

Console output: null

What is the reason? how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want Camel to handle the JSON string to Java object process, you can add it as a marshaller - https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/dataformats/jacksonxml-dataformat.html

Answer (score 1):

The **first option deserializes a String that is a JSON payload to Objects**. It uses Jacksons ObjectMapper to do this.

```
Camel > get body as String
Jackson > parse String to JSON and deserialize it to Objects
```

The second option does not use Jackson, it has no clue about JSON it **tries to cast the payload to User objects**. But this does not work, because the payload is a JSON String.

I assume it does something similar like this

```
if (body instanceof User[]) {
    return (User[]) body;
} else {
    return null;
}
```

Therefore **the return value is `null`** because Camel can't find a User array in the body.

If you **tell Camel what datatype you expect** in the message body but the body **does not contain this datatype, Camel returns `null`**.

Comment: how to adequately correct this in order to immediately deserialize into a user object?

Comment: As long as you receive a JSON payload, you have to use a JSON library to deserialize it. There is no "direct way" to do this. But it is worth it, JSON is portable (works nearly everywhere) and pretty lightweight. Java serialization only works Java-to-Java and couples client and server very tight.

Comment: It is very strange, look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65978493/apache-camel-when-deserializing-an-object-it-throws-an-exception-com-fasterxml, one of the problems was solved with the help new JacksonDataFormat(User[].class)

Comment: I think it must have a solution, otherwise it's terrible code

Comment: Wait, is your question why you have to extract the body as string and deserialize it in a second step? I thought you ask why you have to use Jackson

Comment: The question is why it is not possible to do deserialization in user immediately

Comment: I have extended my answer a bit. If this still not answers your question, please explain your question more exactly.

Comment: Thank you, the correct answer was given above, it was necessary to add unmarshalling